# drawing consecutive lines / raster pattern

Tags: graphics, rasterize

When I try to draw consecutive lines, I start to get aliasing artifacts in my image as my lines get thinner. Am I missing an option which may be causing this? I've tried `Method->ShrinkWrap` and setting all the padding etc. to zero but still no luck.

e.g, this looks ok,

```
x = 1;
rectangles = Table[{Black, Rectangle[{i x, 0}, {i x + x/2, 20}]}, {i, 0, 
    100}];
Graphics[rectangles, ImageSize -> {1000, 1000}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

e.g, but when I double the number of lines,

```
x = 1;
rectangles = Table[{Black, Rectangle[{i x, 0}, {i x + x/2, 20}]}, {i, 0, 
    200}];
Graphics[rectangles, ImageSize -> {1000, 1000}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

I begin to see artifacts.. (Is it my code?)

Thanks,

Edit: 
Method 2 using Raster[]+ImageResize (still artifacts)

```
rect = Table[((-1)^i + 1)/2, {i, 0, 500}];
gra = Graphics[Raster[{rect}], ImageSize -> {1000}];
ImageResize[gra, {1000, 400}]
```

Is it my eyes?

Comment: Menu -> Edit -> Appearance -> Graphics

Comment: no it doesn't seem to be a display error. I can export the image (and even print it) and still see artifacts

Comment: I see no artefacts, maybe it's your screen's resolution.

Comment: In the new images I see two lines which are thinner than the others.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. My question is why? Is it something in my code? Is there a hidden border?

Comment: It's perhaps more fail safe to write `ConstantArray[Riffle[ConstantArray[0, 500], 1], 400] // Image`, it will automatically display at the right size originally. Problems come only from resizing the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose your `ImageSize` is `1000`, naturally in order to properly display the image with two pixels for black and white, you would have `250` white parts and `250` black parts, however

```
Length[rect]
```

> `501`

Which means that two of the black lines will have only `1` pixel each.

Solution?

```
rect = Table[((-1)^i + 1)/2, {i, 0, 500}];
gra = Graphics[Raster[{rect}], ImageSize -> {1002}]
ImageResize[gra, {1002, 400}]
```

[image]

(Click to view properly)

Comment: thanks, so it was just my code, :)